# Find a file with a given name or type in directories with a given name

Tags: bash, find

I want to find all PHP scripts that are inside a directory named `web`. In particular, I'm interested in any files named `index.php` in any of these directories.

I know that I can use `sudo find / -type d -name "web"` to list all the directories, and then I can use `sudo find <directory path> -type f -name "*.php"` for each of the output paths, to see if it contains a PHP script.

But is there a way to do this in one line and two nested find commands: one find command used to get the paths to the `web` directories, and the second to use each of those directories in turn as the root for finding a file whose name matches the pattern `*.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `find` twice if you use the `-path` option instead of `-name`:

```
find / -type f -path "*/web/*.php"
```

Specifically for every file `index.php` located under a directory named `web`:

```
find / -type f -path "*/web/*index.php"
```

Comment: +1, elegant and short :-) but it does not answer the question: 'But is there a way to do this in one line and two nested find commands' ;-)

Comment: @sudodus Oh my, I must've read the question wrong. ;)

Comment: A one line answer without nesting is even better. Thanks to George and @sudodus for showing me how to use -exec.

Comment: You are welcome @JamesNewton :-)

Comment: Is there a way to search with an unknown number of directories between `web` and `*.php`?  What if the php file I'm looking for is several directories deep within the web directory?

Comment: @jschmitter Yes there is, with the `globstar` shell option explained e.g. in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110891/507051) – if this doesn’t do please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

This command should achieve that:

```
find / -type d -name "web" -exec find {}/  -type f -name "*.php" \;
```

Tested on this tree:

```
Documents/askubuntu/web
├── index.php
├── kate
│   ├── jate
│   │   └── jate.php
│   └── kate.php
├── koko
│   └── read.php
└── web2
    └── index.php
```

Result:

```
./Documents/askubuntu/web/koko/read.php
./Documents/askubuntu/web/kate/kate.php
./Documents/askubuntu/web/kate/jate/jate.php
./Documents/askubuntu/web/index.php
./Documents/askubuntu/web/web2/index.php
```