# Find all files in the current directory and its subdirectories with the extension .png

Tags: command-line, ls

In a directory and its subfolders I need to see all the files with the `png` extension.

For this, I used the command `ls -R *.png`

I get an error saying that the directory `*.png` doesn't exist. I am surprised that my regular expression is not recognized.

```
ls: Cannot read '*.png': the file or the directory doesn't exist
```

Comment: ... to find all the files with extension `.png` in the current directory and all its subdirectories, use `find . -name '*.png'` rather than trying to filter the output of `ls -R`

Comment: @steeldriver Tranks you, this command run well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The correct use is

```
 ls -R | grep '\.png$'
```

This command only works with normal file names with no space, new line or special characters. Use `find` as suggested by danzel or globstar as suggested by DoVo.

Comment: `grep .png$` may *appear* to work, but will match *any* character before `png` (not just dot)

Comment: [Do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead).

Answer (score 15):

To *find* files matching a *regular expression*, use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) with the `-regex` option:

```
find [startingPath] -type [fileType] -regex "[regularExpression]"
```

In your case:

- If you want to search for files (file type `f`) ending in `.png`, starting from the current directory:

  ```
  find . -type f -regex ".*\.png"
  ```
- If you want to have an `ls`-like output, use the `-ls` action:

  ```
  find . -type f -regex ".*\.png" -ls
  ```

  (the output has the same format as `ls -dils`).
- If you want to execute a command for each file, use the `-exec` action, e.g.:

  ```
  find . -type f -regex ".*\.png" -exec file {} \;
  ```

  ... will print file type information for each matching file.

There are a lot more things you can do with `find`, just read the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

---

As [@steeldriver said in the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110866/find-all-files-in-the-current-directory-and-its-subdirectories-with-the-extensio/1110880#comment1833352_1110866), there is no regular expression in your command. `*.png` is a shell glob and is expanded *before* `ls` is run. Imagine there are two files in the current directory:

```
picture1.png
picture2.png
```

...then `ls -R *.png` will be expanded to:

```
ls -R picture1.png picture2.png
```

In this case, the `-R` option is not particularly useful because there are no directories specified that `ls` could recurse into.

If the shell doesn't find any matching name, it passes the argument literally (depends on the shell, but bash does):

```
ls -R *.png
```

... and `ls` complains because there is no file called `*.png`.

Comment: +1 as @steeldriver said. But please note that `*` and `.` have different meaning in `-regex ".*\.pdf"` and `-name "*.png"`.

Comment: @PerlDuck good point. `-name` takes a shell pattern (which is matched using the fnmatch function). Since the OP explicitly asked about regular expressions, I concentrated on that.

Answer (score 5):

Another option instead of `find` would be the use of globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
ls **/*.png
```

Optionally unset globstar afterwards:

```
shopt -u globstar
```

---

From `bash` manpage:

```
globstar
    If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will
    match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
    If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and
    subdirectories match.
```